# error 406 not acceptable when i use iframe

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

I am using a form action in Iframe page.(if1.php). I want to navigate to(mail.php) page which is a regular php page. (ie iframe page to another page). The code in iframe page(if1.php) for navigation is shown  below..

```
 <form target="myframe" action="mail.php" method="post">
 <!-- code here -->
 </form>
```

But i am getting the following error when i press a submit button in iframe page(if1.php). Why is this error happening? The browser that I'm using is chrome.

> Not Acceptable An appropriate representation of the requested resource
>   /radical/mail.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: It looks like your path is wrong. tried a fullpath in your action? like `action="http://yourdomain.com/mail.php"`

Comment: This `action` is valid. If no host name is provided, the current host name + path is assumed (notice on can even provide an empty string, then the current URL is assumed). @sudhu, are you sure the URL "http://yourhostname/radical/mail.php" exists? If your ressource URL is actually "http://yourhostname/mail.php" (no "radical") then Kees is right, your `action` is wrong, you need either the absolute URL or a relative one like "../mail.php" (the former is to be preferred IMHO).

Comment: @Kees Sonnema..Thanks..By doing what u said i am getting same error.additionally i am getting my domain name along with the error.Thats it..any other suggestions

Comment: Does your `<iframe>` code looks like this: `<iframe src="your source" name="myform">` ? It could also be that your name is wrong.

Comment: @Yak,Yes absolutely sure about my URL.I hav checked it .It is correct...                                                           URL is :mydomainname/radical/mail.php...ie    <form action =mail.php"> itself..

Comment: `<form action="radical/mail.php">` ? Or am I missing something :p

Comment: @KeesSonnema,Yes it is added:Here is my Iframe code                      <iframe width="523" height="234" scrolling="No"width="500" height="145" src="if1.php" frameborder="0" name="myframe" ></iframe>

Comment: What happens if you access "/radical/mail.php" directly (type this URL in your navigation bar)? I think this issue could be related to an encoding discrepancy (HTTP headers <> actual page encoding).

Comment: @YaK:The mail function in mail.php is working fine(by accessing domainname/radical/mail.php)by typing the url...I am able to send the mail..

Comment: @YaK,@KeesSonnema :Url is navigating properly..But in my error message i am not getting domain name...Can this be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First THANKS for all those who tried helping me in finding the solution ...

The issue was only a "server specific" and not "code specific"...The Server team was able to rectify the issue with some minor changes in server settings and every thing works fine now...

Again many Thanks

Regards,